# .htaccess (and redirect links) on my WordPress site is not working on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mobile, url-rewriting

My website (using WordPress) has an .htaccess file located in the root area with rewrite rules/conditions to redirect certain links. They work just fine using a computer, but when I try accessing those same pages via my BlackBerry mobile device, I get errors.

When I try to access one of my redirected pages on my mobile device, I get this error: "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. You are not authorized to view this page. Please try loading a different page."

You can view what my .htaccess file looks like by viewing the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/GhW4G/.

Do I need to add other pieces of code to the .htaccess file so it allows mobile users to view the pages like computer users can?

Comment: No the should work regardless. Please post the errors and redirect rules?

Comment: Hmmm... okay. Updated my post with .htaccess link and error I receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from its large size, your .htaccess file looks fine to me.

Google tells me that 403 errors on a Blackberry are semi-common. Try clearing your Blackberry's cache?

[How to clear the BlackBerry Browser cache on a BlackBerry smartphone](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do?externalId=KB03865&sliceId=2&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&noCount=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl)

Comment: Turns out that my BlackBerry's software was completely out of date, and I had no idea this whole time. I went ahead and updated it which took a bit, but that seemed to fix the problem. Think I need to be concerned about users who don't have their devices updated? Will I not lose traffic because of that?

Comment: @Omar you might indeed - but there isn't much you can do about that (AFAIK)